# Webpack not uglifying/minifying

Tags: javascript, build, webpack, uglifyjs

I'm using Webpack to build my site, but despite including the `UglifyJsPlugin` in the config, the output doesn't minify.

```
{
    entry: "./dist/client/js/index.js",
    devtool: "source-map",
    loaders: [
        {
            test: /\.js$/,
            loader: "babel",
            query: {
                cacheDirectory: false
            }
        }
    ],
    module: {
        preLoaders: [
            {
                test: /client\\.*\.js$/,
                loader: "source-map-loader"
            }
        ]
    },
    node: {
        child_process: "empty",
        dns: "empty",
        fs: "empty",
        net: "empty"
    },
    output: {
        path: JS_CLIENT_BUILD_PATH,
        filename: JS_BUNDLE_NAME
    },
    plugins: [new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin()]
}
```

Any ideas as to what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try running webpack from the CLI with the `-p` argument.  This essentially adds the Uglify plugin and sets the debug value to false.  This should also minify the output.  If the output is minified I would then point to something incorrect in your configuration.

Comment: Turns out it was a bundled module that was causing problems with Uglify but not with Webpack. Error message was clear when run from the command line.

Comment: thanks! running from the command line identified the issue for me (a module that was missed by the JS loader's test)

Comment: I believe I'm on the same spot, but I can't find any errors and my js file is not minified :( Any thoughts?

Comment: You're probably not specifying the `p` flag

`webpack -p` should do the trick